# Deserialization of xml with simplexml in java

Tags: java, android, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

I'm trying to deserialize an xml string with SimpleXML, i've looked at their examples but i'm not really sure that wether i grasp the concept or not.

Sample XML (validates):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<Response xmlns="http://localhost/webservices/">
<Result>
<Item><ID>0</ID><language /><price>168</price></Item>
<Item><ID>1</ID><language /><price>178</price></Item>
<Item><ID>2</ID><language /><price>195</price></Item>
<Item><ID>3</ID><language /><price>169</price></Item>
<Item><ID>4</ID><language /><price>178</price></Item>
<Item><ID>5</ID><language /><price>178</price></Item>
<Item><ID>6</ID><language /><price>149</price></Item>
<Item><ID>7</ID><language /><price>178</price></Item>
<Item><ID>8</ID><language /><price>168</price></Item>
<Item><ID>9</ID><language /><price>179</price></Item>
<Item><ID>10</ID><language /><price>147</price></Item>
<Item><ID>11</ID><language /><price>165</price></Item>
<Item><ID>12</ID><language /><price>192</price></Item>
<Item><ID>13</ID><language /><price>218</price></Item>
<Item><ID>14</ID><language /><price>144</price></Item>
<Item><ID>15</ID><language /><price>141</price></Item>
</Result>
</Response>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

And the java code:

```
    @Root(name="Result",strict=false)
public class ItemList {

    @ElementList(entry="Item")
    private List<Item> _list;

    public List<Book> GetItemList() 
    {
        return _list;
    }

    public void SetItemList(List<Item> value) 
    {
        this._list = value; 
    }
}

@Root(strict=false)
public class Item {
    @Element(name="ID")
    private String _ID;
    @Element(name="price")
    private String _price;


    public String GetPrice()
    {
        return _price;
    }

    public void SetPrice(String value)
    {
        this._price = value;
    }

    public String GetID()
    {
        return _ID;
    }

    public void SetID(String value) 
    {
        this._ID = value;
    }

    public Item(String ID,
                String price) 
    {
        this._ID = ID;
        this._price = price;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have a suggestion, but it's not ready to run (see below). However, ther maybe another, better solution ...

### Class Item

Holding all your informations.

```
@Root(name="Item")
public class Item
{
    @Element(name="ID", required=true)
    private int id;
    @Element(name="language", required=true)
    private String language;
    @Element(name="price", required=true)
    private int price;


    // ...
}
```

### Class Result

Constructing everything around `Item`. Btw. you dont have to use inner classes here.

```
@Namespace(prefix="soap", reference="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
@Root(name="Envelope")
public class Result
{
    @Namespace(prefix="soap")
    @Element(name="Body")
    private SoapBody body;


    // ...


    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- Some inner classes, constructing the elements as in you xml --
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------


    @Namespace(prefix="soap")
    @Root(name="Body")
    static class SoapBody
    {
        @Element(name="Response")
        private Response response;


        // ...
    }



    @Root(name="Response")
    static class Response
    {
        @ElementList(name="Result", required=true)
        private List<Item> result;


        // ...
    }
}
```

### (Example) How to use this code

**Writing**

```
File f = ...

Serializer ser = new Persister();
Result r = new Result();
ser.write(r, f);
```

**Reading**

```
File f = ...

Serializer ser = new Persister();
Result r = ser.read(Result.class, f);
```

---

Now ... there's one problem which prevents this example from running: `<language />`
This empty Element let SimpleXML throw a `ValueRequiredException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Element( required=false)
    private String language;
```

Add this in your Item class and generate the getter and setter.I think it should work